# indexOf() when array-elements are objects (javascript)

Tags: javascript, arrays, indexof

For instance, a variable named `arrayElements` of type array contains:
`[{id:1, value:5},{id:2, value:6},{id:3, value:7},{id:4, value:8}]`.

How do I get the position of the array element with `id === 3`(3rd element) in the `arrayElements` variable besides using loop?

thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to loop at one point. But you can abstract it to look like you're not looping

```js
function indexOfCallback(arr, callback, startIndex) {
    if (typeof startIndex == 'undefined') {
        startIndex = 0;
    }
    for(var i=startIndex; i < arr.length; i ++) {
        if (callback(arr[i])) {
            return i;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}

var array = [{id:1, value:5},{id:2, value:6},{id:3, value:7},{id:4, value:8}];
// Search on id === 3
console.log(indexOfCallback(array, function(obj){
    return obj.id === 3;
}));
// Search on value === 6
console.log(indexOfCallback(array, function(obj){
    return obj.value === 6;
}));
```

As mentioned by Anthony, this is proposed for ECMAScript 6. Here's the more complete polyfill https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex

```
if (!Array.prototype.findIndex) {
  Array.prototype.findIndex = function(predicate) {
    if (this == null) {
      throw new TypeError('Array.prototype.find called on null or undefined');
    }
    if (typeof predicate !== 'function') {
      throw new TypeError('predicate must be a function');
    }
    var list = Object(this);
    var length = list.length >>> 0;
    var thisArg = arguments[1];
    var value;

    for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
      value = list[i];
      if (predicate.call(thisArg, value, i, list)) {
        return i;
      }
    }
    return -1;
  };
}
console.log(array.findIndex(function(obj){
    return obj.id === 3;
}));
```

Comment: MDN has a listing for an experimental/proposed array iteration function, [`findIndex()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex), which seems to be much the same thing. For now definitely want to implement something like this for yourself, but perhaps at some point there won't be a need to.

Answer (score 4):

```
const arrayElements = [
  { id: 1, value: 5 },
  { id: 2, value: 6 },
  { id: 3, value: 7 },
  { id: 4, value: 8 }
]

console.log(arrayElements.findIndex((item) => item.id === 3))
```

Comment: This is now the correct answer.

Comment: The answer is a bit poor. You should add a link to the doc : https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex

Answer (score 3):

```
arrayElements.map(o => o.id).indexOf(3);
```

Notes:

- Possibly slower than a loop because transforms whole array prior to
  search. But with high-level languages like Javascript, you never
  know.
- Infinitely more readable than a loop.
- IE compatible (unlike [findIndex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) as of 2017).

Comment: thanks for your answer, but damn, that question is two years old... :D

Comment: @JulianBerger: **1.** Good questions are ageless. **2.** You talk like a mortal. Two years is nothing for us. We have answered questions that were two _thousand_ years old. **3.** I’m glad that you are alive. We may not be so fortunate when we answer your questions a hundred years later. We will still try though. **4.** *Quid biennium ad æonem? Quid est hoc in die ævi? Quanta arenula in Terrae mole, quanta gutta in Oceano, quanta scintilla in Sole – sic exiguum est biennium in die ævi.*

Answer (score 0):

In an array like this, you cant access elements by id. So using a loop is the best solution you have. However, depending on your use case you could also consider using an object instead of an array for direct access.

```
var container = { 1: {id:1, value:5}, 2: {id:2, value:6}, 3: {id:3, value:7} }
```

Answer (score -1):

I wrote a function for you that you can use get the job done, but it uses a loop:

```
var yourObjArray = [{id:1, value:5},{id:2, value:6},{id:3, value:7},{id:4, value:8}];


function objArrayIndex(objArray){
  for(var i = 0; i < objArray.length; i++){
    if(objArray[i]['id'] == 3){
      return i;
    }
  }
  return -1;
}

console.log(objArrayIndex(yourObjArray));
```

Comment: That's a bad abstraction, you have to write a new function with a new loop if you want to search on a different property or a different value

Comment: good point.  but it is a simple solution to ops troubles meant to illustrate the kind of thing he needs to do

Comment: I don't think the OP doesn't know how to use a for loop. See my solution for a reusable function http://stackoverflow.com/a/26739030/227299

Comment: It's a little hard to tell why OP doesn't want to use a loop, but I've edited my answer to get rid of the word 'abstraction.'

Comment: I actually think the OP **is** looking for an abstraction. They want something like `indexOf`, it lets you search an array by specifying what to find as a parameter, but in this case you can't just pass an object that is like it, because they won't pass the equal test. The solution is to let the caller implement the equality function as a callback. Again, see my answer.

Comment: i was looking for something without defining a new function. i have to compair two values, knowing the objects id. and i wanted to do it without an additional function...

Answer (score -1):

You can use an array filter but I think that you will get a better solution using a loop.

```
var array = [{id:1, value:5},{id:2, value:6},{id:3, value:7},{id:4, value:8}];

var result = array.filter(condition);

function condition(value, index){
    if (value.id === 3) return index;
}

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Who upvoted this? This returns an array with objects that meet the criteria, it doesn't return the index that is returned from the callback. Even worse, this won't even filter correctly when the first item matches the condition.